# In asp.net , what is the difference between gridview and repeater controls

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, repeater

I have worked with both the controls for simple application development . Both almost do the same functionality. What is the difference between them ?

Comment: See [Repeater Web Server Control Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x8f2zez5.aspx) and [GridView Web Server Control Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2s019wc0.aspx)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a table here that compares the data bound server controls:

http://weblogs.asp.net/anasghanem/archive/2008/09/06/comparing-listview-with-gridview-datalist-and-repeater.aspx

Answer (score 1):

GridView always renders as a grid.  Repeater allows you to create your own template layout.  For instance, you can put things in divs.  GridView also has a much more rich object model, while repeater is rather simplistic.

Yes, you can achieve similar results with both, but they are nowhere near the same thing.

Comment: Not necessarily... GridView also supports ItemTemplate and other rendering tags. You can put things in div in GridView as well

Answer (score 0):

Both these controls are Data-Bound Web Server control.

`GridView` : It displays data as a table and has ability to preform sort, paging,edit and delete a record.

`Repeater` : has fewer templates then GridView. It renders a read-only list from the datasource.