# Difference between Gridview and Repeaters in ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net

Can I know the exact difference between gridview and repeater in asp.net.
Also if i am retrieving the value from database dynamically what option would be feasible if I want to edit a particular record from it.
Please help me out as i am new to ASP.Net
Thanks in advance...

Comment: did you try searching on google?

Comment: Already asked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7328134/in-asp-net-what-is-the-difference-between-gridview-and-repeater-controls

Answer (score 2):

**The `GridView`** : it supports paging but it doesn't provide a flexible layout , since its mainly used to display the data in a table based layout.And If we looked at data inserting , the Gridview doesn't have a built in support for inserting data( since it doesn't call the insert method of it underlying data source when you click on a button with a CommadName set to "Insert" ).

**The Repeater control** : you will find that it provides a flexible layout but it doesn't support data grouping ,inserting,deleting , updating  and paging through the data .

The Repeater and GridView controls are used differently.  A GridView control is used when you want to display a set of data in a table format.  A Repeater is when you want to display data repeatedly, but not necessarily in a tabular format.  If you want a table, use a GridView, otherwise use a Repeater.  The speed of loading/updating is negligible between the two.  It sounds like the GridView is what you are probably looking for.

Answer (score 1):

This may give some ideas about the different between repeater and gridview, 
[Repeater, ListView, DataList, DataGrid, GridView ... Which to choose?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/139207/repeater-listview-datalist-datagrid-gridview-which-to-choose)

You can use events like

- YourGridViewID_RowEditing
- YourGridViewID_RowUpdating
- YourGridViewID_RowDataBound

and more to do things like edit/update/delete, etc with the value in a row. 
You'll get many hits if you google these event names.

Repeaters also provide events like

- YourRepeaterID_ItemDataBound

Hope this helps you start.

Answer (score 0):

http://weblogs.asp.net/gunnarpeipman/archive/2008/07/25/gridview-or-repeater.aspx

If you need to edit go with GridView.